# How to parse security certificate subcomponents?

Tags: java, regex, ldap, certificate

I'm reading the subject from a security certificate, which has the following format...

```
CN=x,OU=y,O=z,ST=v,C=COM
```

I want to parse this `String` and get the `CN` only. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: BTW: Java 5.0 has been End Of Life for more than a year, have you   considered using Java 6?

Comment: I saw that in JDK5 there is solution for this issue, but I can't upgrade my jdk.

Comment: I would not even suggest you upgrade to Java 5.0. ;) But if you cannot upgrade ...

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to use simple regular expressions here?

Without tried it and out of my mind:

```
Pattern pattern  = Pattern.compile("CN=([^\\,])\\,")
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if ( matcher.find() )
{
  for (int index=1; index<matcher.groupCount();index++)
  {
    String cnValue = matcher.group(index);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working version of Omnaest's answer:

```
Pattern pattern  = Pattern.compile("CN=([^\\,]*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
String cnValue = matcher.find() ? matcher.group(1) : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CompoundName of jndi

```
Name dn = parser.parse("CN=x,OU=y,O=z,ST=v,C=COM");
dn.get(dn.size());
```

For an example have a look at this [link](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.naming/ParseCompound.html)

**Edit: Added a working example**

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    try {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:389");
        Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
        NameParser parser = ctx.getNameParser("");
        Name dn = parser.parse("CN=x,OU=y,O=z,ST=v,C=COM");

        System.out.println(dn.size() + dn.get( dn.size() -1  ));
    }catch(NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To create the context you have to connect to a ldap server however. Its easy to do a string parsing and get the first rdn. But do not get there! The DN have different formats. In DCE format the dn will be separated as CN=x/OU=y/O=z/ST=v/C=COM

**EDIT: Added another example without connecting to ldap server**

```
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapName;
....

public static void main(String args[]){

  try {
      LdapName dn = new LdapName("CN=x,OU=y,O=z,ST=v,C=COM");
      System.out.println(dn.get(dn.size() - 1));
  }catch (InvalidNameException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: try { NameParser parser = ctx.getNameParser(""); Name dn = parser.parse("cn=John, ou=People, o=JNDITutorial"); dn.remove(1); // ou=People dn.add(0, "c=us"); // cn=John,o=JNDITutorial,c=us dn.add("cn=fs"); // cn=fs,cn=John,o=JNDITutorial,c=us } catch (NamingException e) { } What is ctx?

Comment: @Mattan it is a javax.naming.Context of some description.

Comment: I couldn't understand how to parse it. I have the string, and nothing else. How can I get the cn from the whole string?

Comment: Thanks kalyan. The problem is that I don't always have ldap server. I'm reading the whole string from the subject field in a client certificate. So I can't connect to an ldap server. Do you have other solution?