# Is there a way to recover the common name of a client certificate from java code in a 2 way ssl connection?

Tags: java, soap, ssl, weblogic

We have a weblogic server configured to require a client certificate on stablishing a ssl connection with client for a web service solution. The ssl handshake works perfectly as we have already configured all that is required.

Now, after the connection we do receive a soap request where the client id is one of the fields of this request soap. 
What we need to do is to check this id against the common name of the client certificate used to connect within our server in order to garantee the transaction. 
This is very important to us because this is a bank transaction and there is a lot of money involved in it and we need to avoid frauds.

So: Is there a way to recover the common name of a client certificate used to stablish a 2 way ssl connection from java code running on the server using a weblogic 10.3.3 server?

[]s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The client's certificate can be read from the incoming Servlet request using the [`HttpServletRequest.getAttribute(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) method invocation. The attribute with name [`javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html) is populated by the servlet container when it creates an instance of the Request object for processing by the servlet/webservice.

The DN of the certificate can then be obtained from the X500Principal object, obtained from the certificate object via the [`getX500Principal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getSubjectX500Principal%28%29) method invocation. This does not give the CN, but will provide your with the complete distinguished name in a specified format; [this could be parsed to provide the CN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800896/how-to-parse-name-subcomponents).

As far as accessing the ServletRequest object is concerned, JAX-WS web services can be programmed to read the [MessageContext](http://jax-ws.java.net/articles/MessageContext.html) which allows access to the underlying HttpServletRequest object.

Comment: Hi Vineet I will try this approach and let you know of the results.

Comment: +1, and `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate` is an array of `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` (representing the chain if needed). Index 0 is where the client certificate is. In addition, when parsing for the CN, you should be aware that there may be more than one in a DN.

Comment: We tryied the suggested impl but we get a null object when using: X509Certificate x509Cert = (X509Certificate)httpSR.getAttribute("X509Certificate"); 
Maybe the key for this servlet request attribute is not correct. So I will try now the complete name: javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate and let you know.

Comment: It worked: Implemented like: (Jax-WS web service): 
@Resource
WebServiceContext
wsCtx;
MessageContext msgCtx =
wsCtx.getMessageContext();
HttpServletRequest httpSR = (HttpServletRequest)msgCtx.get(MessageContext.
SERVLET_REQUEST
);
String x500Prin =
"";
try {
       X509Certificate[] x509Cert = (X509Certificate[])httpSR.getAttribute(
"javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
       x500Prin = x509Cert[0].getSubjectX500Principal().getName();

}

catch (Exception e) {
       log.severe("Erro ao instanciar certificado =======> " + e.getMessage());
}
System.out.println("x500Prin: " + x500Prin);