# Any way to identify callers programmatically on two-way HTTPS secured JBoss as 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ssl, jboss, https

I have a webservice deployed on JBoss as 7 and secured with two-way SSL. In order to identify the callers of the service, currently they're required to provide username/password pair as well. So that I can identify them by using the following code.

```
String username = (String) wsContext.getMessageContext()
                               .get(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY);
```

However, I think theoretically it's possible to identify them after the process of SSL handshake. It could be a possible way by providing a customised TrustManager which possibly knows what certificate is using. I just wonder if there is any simple/better way. Even just return something about the certificate which can be used to identify.

Any help would be appreciated.

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a custom TrustManager for that. The client SSL certificate chain is available in a request attribute [`javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks for the clue. Based on your answer I found the following link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179450/is-there-a-way-to-recover-the-common-name-of-a-client-certificate-from-java-code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179450/is-there-a-way-to-recover-the-common-name-of-a-client-certificate-from-java-code).